# The expected type comes from property 'nfts' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & NftListProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I'm a beginner in react typescript. I don't know how to resolve this problem.

```
import { FunctionComponent } from "react";
import NftItem from "../item";

type NftListProps = {
    nfts: any[]
  }

const NftList: FunctionComponent<NftListProps> = ({nfts}) =>
{
    return(
        <div className="mt-12 max-w-lg mx-auto grid gap-5 lg:grid-cols-3 lg:max-w-none">
            {nfts.map(nft => 
                <div key={nft.image} className="flex flex-col rounded-lg shadow-lg overflow-hidden">
                    <NftItem/>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

export default NftList;
```

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next';
import { BaseLayout, NftList } from '../components';
import nfts from "../content/meta.json"

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <BaseLayout>
    <div> Welcome !</div>
      <div className="relative bg-gray-50 pt-16 pb-20 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:pt-24 lg:pb-28 lg:px-8">
        <div className="absolute inset-0">
          <div className="bg-white h-1/3 sm:h-2/3" />
        </div>
        <div className="relative">
          <div className="text-center">
            <h2 className="text-3xl tracking-tight font-extrabold text-gray-900 sm:text-4xl">Metaverse</h2>
            <p className="mt-3 max-w-2xl mx-auto text-xl text-gray-500 sm:mt-4"> ABC
            </p>
          </div>
          <NftList 
            nfts={nfts}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </BaseLayout>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Type

```
{
    "description": "Fierce violet creature. Very durable and tanky.",
    "image": "https://eincode.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmaQYCrX9Fg2kGijqapTYgpMXV7QPPzMwGrSRfV9TvTsfM/Creature_1.png",
    "name": "Eincode Creature #1",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "trait_type": "attack",
        "value": "20"
      },
      {
        "trait_type": "health",
        "value": "100"
      },
      {
        "trait_type": "speed",
        "value": "30"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I got an error at `<NftList nfts={nfts}/>` with the error content is "The expected type comes from property 'nfts' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & NftListProps"
Do you guys have any ideas to resolve it?
Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

The error arose due to the incorrect type or incorrect data provided into your **NftList** component.

First, you have to make sure that your **Nft** data in `meta.json` is **stored in an array** like this:

```
[
  {
    "description": "Fierce violet creature. Very durable and tanky.",
    "image": "https://eincode.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmaQYCrX9Fg2kGijqapTYgpMXV7QPPzMwGrSRfV9TvTsfM/Creature_1.png",
    "name": "Eincode Creature #1",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "trait_type": "attack",
        "value": "20"
      },
      {
        "trait_type": "health",
        "value": "100"
      },
      {
        "trait_type": "speed",
        "value": "30"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "description": "Strongest creature. Powerful and unexhausted strength.",
    "image": "https://eincode.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmaQYCrX9Fg2kGijqapTYgpMXV7QPPzMwGrSRfV9TvTsfM/Creature_2.png",
    "name": "Eincode Creature #2",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "trait_type": "attack",
        "value": "100"
      },
      {
        "trait_type": "health",
        "value": "100"
      },
      {
        "trait_type": "speed",
        "value": "100"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Next, you should create **Nft** and **Trait** type:

```
type Trait = {
  trait_type: string;
  value: string;
};

type Nft = {
  description: string;
  image: string;
  name: string;
  attributes: Trait[];
};
```

And let's assume that your **NftItem** component like this:

```
interface NftItemProps {
  nft: Nft;
}

const NftItem = ({ nft }: NftItemProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{nft.name}</h1>
      <p>{nft.description}</p>
      <img src={nft.image} alt={nft.name} />
      <ul>
        {nft.attributes.map((attr, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index}>
              <span>{attr.trait_type}</span>
              <span>{attr.value}</span>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And your simplified **NftList** component where you map your **nfts** array like this:

```
interface NftListProps {
  nfts: Nft[];
}

const NftList = ({ nfts }: NftListProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {nfts.map((nft, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <NftItem nft={nft} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

So you can use the **NftList** component in your page as follow:

```
const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <BaseLayout>
      ...
      <div> Welcome !</div>
      <NftList nfts={nfts}/>
      ...
    </BaseLayout>
  )
}
```

[image: Edit amazing-yonath-dnmdw1]

Comment: Thank you. I've resolved this with your solution!